# Laravel routes with regex portions that don't get passed as parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Is there any way I can have a route set up with one regex section that doesn't get passed as a parameter?

For example:

```
Route::get('{string}/method/{id}', function($id)
{
    return 'only one parameter passed, ID is ' . $id;
});
```

Specifically I'm routing to a controller and the methods need to be compatible with routes coming from elsewhere, which don't include this first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is that, routes has to be matched according to it's declaration, for example, if you define a route like your example here

```
Route::get('{string}/method/{id}', function($id)
{
    return 'only one parameter passed, ID is ' . $id;
});
```

Then the requested `url` has to be matched with same numbers of parameters including the `http` method (GET here) and in this case, the route will match only with something like this

```
httP//example.com/something/method/10
```

Here the second parameter `10` is not bound to be digits because you didn't make it to be a digit using `where(...)` so, it could be anything but two parameters must be required.

As an alternative, you may define a `missing` method in your controller like this (An idea only)

```
public function missingMethod($args = array())
{
    // $args will contain all parameters
}
```

This is a special method in `Laravel` that any controller may contain it and whenever a non-existing method will be called in that controller, then this `missingMethod` would be called and all the parameters will be passed to it's `$args` parameter as an array, so if you have two parameters in the `url` and calling method is missing in the controller then you may get those parameters within this method scope, something like `[param1, param2]` and from this method you may call your desired method depending on the count of `params`.

So, if you just point the route's action to this controller which has the missing method then from the `missingMethod` you may call another method using different parameters according to your other method.

Also check [PHP Overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) and [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) to get the real idea of `missingMethod`.